# I have 2 tabs ,how can i reset to the pages to starting page after navigation from other page

Tags: android, webview, tabs

i have 2 tabs with webviews .I need code to reset the page when navigate back to the first page  from second page(exactly like the stating page).but here the page is not reloading.

[First page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2DUN.png) )

[first page expansion when a link is cliked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLVfy.png)

Comment: add an observer of events when you slide between pages

Comment: can you please simplify your question? it is confusing

Comment: simply when i naviagate back from second page to first page of tabview it should be reloaded.But in my program it is not reloading